# AWS RDS - unable to drop database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are unable to drop the database which is in AWS RDS.

When we are trying to drop the database it's below error,

```
`Error Code: 1010. Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\folderpath')`
```

We are unable to remove directly in the folder as it's a managed service

We are unable to drop the database because it's showing error 1010

Comment: How are you attempting to delete the database? Any specific commands? Can you please show the full output?

Comment: We are using SQL yog with drop database 'databadename' command. Complete error is Error Code: 1010. Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\path', errno: 39)